# Ozonolysis of nitronate

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, ozone

What is the mechanism for the ozonolysis of a nitronate anion? What gas is produced in this reaction? Is there any chemoselectivity in the presence of a double C=C bond in the molecule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the mechanism for the ozonolysis of a nitronate anion?

Probably very analogous to ozonolysis of a double bond.

[image]

A typical synthetic procedure is detailed in [OrgSyn](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=cv6p0648).  Note the addition of dimethylsulfide during work-up; this is common in ozonolysis reactions as it helps reduce the ozonide and also reduces any other dangerous, highly oxidized by-products.  The discussion section of the OrgSyn article says,

> "There are various methods available for transforming a nitro group
>   into a carbonyl group, including the Nef reaction (strongly acidic),²
>   permanganate oxidation of nitronate anions (basic, oxidative),³
>   persulfate oxidation of nitronates (basic, oxidative),⁴ treatment with
>   a mixture of organic and inorganic nitrite (neutral, oxidative),⁵ and
>   treatment of either a free nitro compound or a nitronate anion with
>   aqueous titanium(III) (neutral, reductive).⁶ Each method is limited,
>   however, by poor yield, inconvenience, or lack of generality.
>
> With the proviso that the substrate not contain a reactive
>   carbon-carbon double bond, the present ozonolysis procedure⁷ appears
>   to provide a convenient and efficient method for carrying out the
>   desired "

The [Nef Reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nef_reaction) is mentioned above, it is worth taking a look at the linked article since the Nef reaction is complementary to the ozonolysis reaction of nitronates.  You may also find the "Reaction mechanism" section interesting.

> What gas is produced in this reaction?

According to the above mechanism, no gas would be generated, rather $\ce{NO3^{-}}$ is produced

> Is there any chemoselectivity in the presence of a double C=C bond in the molecule?

No, as mentioned in the OrgSyn reference, this approach can't be used when other double bonds are present.

Comment: what do you mean by DMS helping reduce other highly oxidized by-products? What could they be, and why would they be dangerous?

Comment: @Dissenter  Ozonolysis is not a delicate reaction, lots of things get oxidized and chewed up.  Hydroperoxides, peroxides and tetroxanes can be formed in the process and they are all explosive.  A dialkyl sulfide can reduce them to less dangerous by-products.